# multiple rows in one after join

Tags: r

i have to join two dataframes. the joining is working properly, my only problem is:

sometimes i have 2 rows in a dataset, that have to be joined with the other dataset. after the joining the rows are displayed directly one below the other. I need them in one row:

here a small example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1:5), 
                  B = c(12, 13, 14, 15, 16),
                  C = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))

df2 <- data.frame(A = c(1,1,2,2,3), 
                  E = c(112, 145, 546, 674, 287),
                  J = c("t", "e", "v", "p", "s"))

merged <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = "A")
```

---

```
 A | B | c |  E  | J |  
---------------------
 1 | 12| a | 112 | t 
 1 | 12| a | 145 | e 
 2 | 13| b | 546 | v 
 2 | 13| b | 674 | p 
 3 | 14| c | 287 | s
```

i need it this way:

```
 A | B | c |  E.x | J.x |  E.y | J.y 
--------------------------------
 1 | 12| a | 112  | t   | 145  | e
 2 | 13| b | 546  | v   | 674  | p
```

all joined rows together in one row in the new dataset

thank you for your help
derlu

```
**update:**
```

My original data frames have

1. 354 items with 1535 observation
2. 246 items 203 observation

They are merged by the first column  `id_merge`. Sometimes I have 2 matches, sometimes 3 identical „id_merge“ values.

Comment: You can't have a dataframe with multiple columns with the same name.

Comment: I know. I edited my question. This isn’t the problem

Comment: I'm not sure to understand where the x and y come from. If you can formalise this and create a new column, then `dcast() ` from `reshape2`should help you.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to split up the dataframe by occurrence of each key, and then do another join.  First, we create a key (`n`) and split up the dataframe:

```
merged <- merged %>% 
  group_by(A, B, C) %>%
  mutate(n = 1:n())
#       A     B C         E J         n
#   <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <fct> <int>
# 1     1    12 a       112 t         1
# 2     1    12 a       145 e         2
# 3     2    13 b       546 v         1
# 4     2    13 b       674 p         2
# 5     3    14 c       287 s         1

merged_list <- split(merged, merged$n) %>%
  map(select, -n)
# $`1`
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
# # Groups:   A [3]
#       A     B C         E J    
#   <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <fct>
# 1     1    12 a       112 t    
# 2     2    13 b       546 v    
# 3     3    14 c       287 s    

# $`2`
# # A tibble: 2 x 5
# # Groups:   A [2]
#       A     B C         E J    
#   <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <fct>
# 1     1    12 a       145 e    
# 2     2    13 b       674 p
```

Then use `Reduce` to join the dataframes:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) left_join(x, y, by = c("A", "B", "C")),
       merged_list)
#       A     B C       E.x J.x     E.y J.y  
#   <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <fct>
# 1     1    12 a       112 t       145 e    
# 2     2    13 b       546 v       674 p    
# 3     3    14 c       287 s        NA NA
```

Comment: I will try this example with my datasets. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not cool these days, but Base R's `reshape` actually shines for this as it deals with unequal group sizes and labelling all in one go. You need to add a `time` variable first though to label each group:

```
merged <- merge(df1, cbind(df2, time=ave(df2$A, df2$A, FUN=seq_along)), by="A")
reshape(merged, idvar=names(df1), direction="wide", sep="_")
#  A  B C E_1 J_1 E_2  J_2
#1 1 12 a 112   t 145    e
#3 2 13 b 546   v 674    p
#5 3 14 c 287   s  NA <NA>
```

It actually fits in a dplyr pipeline not too bad:

```
df2 %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  mutate(time=row_number()) %>%
  inner_join(df1,.,by="A") %>%
  reshape(idvar=names(df1), direction="wide", sep="_")
```

Comment: with the given example it works great. with my data not. tells me: `Fehler in [.data.frame(data, , idvar) : undefined columns selected`. `idvar=names(datensatz_selbst)`works great and gives me the right columnames

Comment: Genau! You must change the names to match the datasets you are working with, but the concept should stay the same.

Comment: Ok. Ich steh auf dem Schlauch. Ich hab es analog zum Bsp auf meine beiden Datensätze angewandt. Doch bekomme immer einen Fehler. Finde diesen aber nicht. Hängt es ab der Länge des Datensätzen? An der Anzahl der Var?

Comment: (My German understanding is very basic, but I think I follow). It depends on the number of variables. The first part of the code depends on `"A"` - which represents your `by=` variable(s) for the join. The second part of the code, used in `idvar=`, is *all* the variables in your first dataset that make up the unique identifiers for a row.

Comment: The first three commands work perfectly. The datasets are merged. The error comes with the 4th command. He got issues with the reshaping.

Comment: i could send you an example of my data. so can have a look

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`, you can split each group of `(E, J)` rows having the same `(A, B, C)` values by row, and `cbind` that list together. Here `.I` is the row number, `.N` is the number of rows in the group, and `.SD` is the group of rows.

This only works if the number of repeated rows is the same in all groups (except for groups with 1 row)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(merged)

merged[, if(.N > 1) do.call(cbind, split(.SD, .I))
       , by = .(A, B, C)]

#    A  B C 1.E 1.J 2.E 2.J
# 1: 1 12 a 112   t 145   e
# 2: 2 13 b 546   v 674   p
```

Comment: The numbers of rows differ. First dataset 1513, second 203. but thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It will be like this and applicable for larger datasets as well

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1:5), 
              B = c(12, 13, 14, 15, 16),
              C = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))

df2 <- data.frame(A = c(1,1,2,2,3), 
              E = c(112, 145, 546, 674, 287),
              J = c("t", "e", "v", "p", "s"))

 df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by=c("A"))

 df4 <- data.frame()

 for (j in 1:(nrow(df3)-1))
     for (k in (j+1):nrow(df3))
         for (i in 2:ncol(df3))
             if(df3[j,1] == df3[k,1] && all(df3[j,i:ncol(df3)]!=df3[k,i:ncol(df3)])){
                 if(nrow(df4) == 0)
                      df4 <- data.frame(c(df3[j,],df3[k,i:ncol(df3)]))
                  else
                      df4 <- rbind(df4,c(df3[j,],df3[k,i:ncol(df3)]))
                  break
              }
```